# Moya 8 to 16, Swift 3.2 to 5 (как переписать код?)

Tags: swift, сеть

Есть код написаный под Swift 3.2 и Moya 8 версии.
Он работал, а при переходе на Swift 5 и Moya 16 версии выдает ошибки:

> 1. Missing argument for parameter 'completion' in call
> 2. Value of type 'Cancellable' has no member 'catchError'

```
let NetworkProvider = MoyaProvider<Network>(endpointClosure: endpointClosure,
plugins: plugins)

class NetworkAPI {
    
    private init() { }

    private class func requestWrapper(_ token: Network) -> Observable<Response> {
        return NetworkProvider
            .request(token) // 1 -ошибка
            .catchError({ (error: Swift.Error) -> Observable<Response> in // 2-ошибка
                guard let moyaError: MoyaError = error as? MoyaError else {
                    throw error
                }
                
                guard case let MoyaError.underlying(underlyingError) = moyaError else {
                    throw error
                }

                guard let afError: AFError = underlyingError as? AFError,
                    afError.responseCode == 401
                    else { throw error }
                
                return refreshToken()
                    .flatMap({ (_: RefreshResult) -> Observable<Response> in 
                        return NetworkProvider.request(token)
                    }) 
            })
        
    }
}
```

Не могу понять, что тут изменилось у Moya, чтобы все заработало, поэтому прошу помощи.

Попробовал сделать так:

```
class NetworkAPI {
        
        private init() { }
    
        private class func requestWrapper(_ token: Network) -> Observable<Response> {
            return NetworkProvider.rx //тут изменения  
                .request(token) 
                .asObservable() //тут добавлено
                .catchError({ (error: Swift.Error) -> Observable<Response> in 
                    guard let moyaError: MoyaError = error as? MoyaError else {
                        throw error
                    }
                    
                    guard case let MoyaError.underlying(underlyingError) = moyaError else {
                        throw error
                    }
    
                    guard let afError: AFError = underlyingError as? AFError,
                        afError.responseCode == 401
                        else { throw error }
                    
                    return refreshToken() // 1-ошибка
                        .flatMap({ (_: RefreshResult) -> Observable<Response> in // 2-ошибка
                            return NetworkProvider.request(token)
                        }) 
                })
            
        }
    }
```

Появилась ошибки в другом месте:

> 1. Declared closure result 'Cancellable' is incompatible with contextual type 'Observable'
> 2. Missing argument for parameter 'completion' in call

Вообщем нужна помощь...

Comment: В ошибках же всё написано, что не так.

Comment: Так вот я что-то никак и не пойму, а результат то раньше был и тип был правильный...

Answer (score 1):

Во втором запросе тоже нужен был .rx и немного изменился тип ответа.
Вдруг кому пригодиться:

```
class NetworkAPI {
  private init() { }
  private class func requestWrapper(_ token: Network) -> Observable<Response> {
    return NetworkProvider.rx
       .request(token) 
       .asObservable()
       .catchError({ (error: Swift.Error) -> Observable<Response> in 
          guard let moyaError: MoyaError = error as? MoyaError else {
               throw error
          }
                    
          guard case let MoyaError.underlying(underlyingError) = moyaError else {
                        throw error
          }
    
          guard let afError: AFError = underlyingError as? AFError,               
                                       afError.responseCode == 401
                        else { throw error }
                    
           return refreshToken()
               .flatMap({ (_: RefreshResult) -> Single<Response>
                       return NetworkProvider.rx.request(token)
                }) 
           })
            
        }
    }
```